# Use google drive before login in ?Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, auto-login, google-drive

So the integration for Google Drive in Ubuntu 18.04 is great in the gui, but I would like to use it on a server (this may be still running the desktop version of Ubuntu 18.04 for other reasons). As part of this we will have gitlab set up on it and we want to do backups of gitlab to a google drive account (so that we don't have to worry about offsite backups). However, I would like to make it so that when booted the machine will not auto login (for obvious security reasons), but that means I don't have access to google drive. Is there a way that I can access google drive when not logged in (ie so that I can run a cron job to backup to google drive)?